# awk - How to extract quoted string in space delimited log file

Tags: awk

I'm hoping there might be some simple way to do this, as I'm a total novice using awk.

I have a bunch of log files from an AWS load balancer, and I want to extract entries from these logs, where a particular response code was received.

Checking the response code is easy enough, I can do the following...

```
$9=="403" {print $0}
```

However what I really want is just the request itself, $13, However this column is quoted, and will contain spaces. It looks like so...

```
"GET https://[my domain name]:443/[my path] HTTP/2.0"
```

If I do the following...

```
$9=="403" {print $13}
```

I just get...

```
"GET
```

So what I think I need to do, is for awk (or some other appropriate utility) to extract the complete column 13, and then be able to break that down into it's individual fields, for method, URL etc.

Comment: can you add a sample entire log line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newer version `gawk` has a built-in variable `FPAT` which you can use to define fields by a regex pattern. For your logs, if no other quoted fields before the field 9 and 13:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^[:space:]]+|"[^"]*"' '$9 == "403"{print $13}' log_file
```

REF: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. I have given inside regex of `match` 443  as per your sample to match it you could give it as per your need to look for `403` change it to `match($0,/\".*403.*\"/)` too.

```
awk 'match($0,/\".*443.*\"/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

IMHO advantage of this approach will be you need NOT to hard code any field number in your `awk`. 1 more thing I have assumed that your Input_file will have `"......403....."` kind of section only once and you want to print that only.

1 more additional `awk` where I am assuming you may have multiple occurrences of `"..."` so picking only that one where `403|443` is coming.

```
awk 'match($0,/\".*443[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)}' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Or if your Input_file has `"...443..."` one time or  this text is coming first after starting of line(assuming if other occurrences of `".."` will come later) then you could try following.

```
awk -F'"' '/443/{print $2}' Input_file
```

Comment: @user1751825, Could you please let me know here if this solution helped you?